# How to install JSON.NET using NuGet?

Tags: nuget

I am trying to download JSON.NET from NuGet.
Is it available? What's the correct command?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can do this a couple of ways.

**Via the "Solution Explorer"**

1. Simply right-click the "References" folder and select "Manage NuGet Packages..."
2. Once that window comes up click on the option labeled "Online" in the left most part of the dialog.
3. Then in the search bar in the upper right type "json.net"
4. Click "Install" and you're done.

**Via the "Package Manager Console"**

1. Open the console. "View" > "Other Windows" > "Package Manager Console"
2. Then type the following:

   ```
   Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
   ```

For more info on how to use the "Package Manager Console" check out the [nuget docs](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console).

Comment: Will this be saved into the Visual Studio solution so anyone else opening it will get the same package installed?

Comment: Yes. It will be stored in a packages folder within the solution's directory structure.

Comment: I can't get this to work with visual studio express 2008, is there another way?

Comment: @RickardB. yes and no. Since the express versions of Visual Studio don't allow for extensions you will have to use the command line version of NuGet found at http://nuget.codeplex.com. One caveat with this method is the fact that your project will need to be linked to the dependency you retrieve from the NuGet servers.

Comment: @Mateo, Thank you for the answer. I assumed that might be the case, so i installed VS 2013 community edition instead. Works like a charm!

Comment: As a side note, newer versions of Visual Studio seem to include this if you create a WebAPI project.

Answer (score 2):

I have Had the same issue and the only Solution i found was
open Package manager> Select Microsoft and .Net as Package Source and You will install it..

[image]