# Calling and get result text from service

Tags: c#, json

I have service url : [please check it](http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/export?bbox=9153621.1267%2C-644273.9207%2C13435472.9966%2C3637577.9492&bboxSR=&layers=&layerdefs=&size=800%2C600&imageSR=&format=png&transparent=false&dpi=&time=&layerTimeOptions=&f=pjson), It's return json string.

I don't know how to call this url by using `C#`

Then. By the link, you can see `"href"` in json data. It's have `.png` url. I would like to save that image to my local disk.

**Question**

1. How to get and read json data from this [service](http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/export?bbox=9153621.1267%2C-644273.9207%2C13435472.9966%2C3637577.9492&bboxSR=&layers=&layerdefs=&size=800%2C600&imageSR=&format=png&transparent=false&dpi=&time=&layerTimeOptions=&f=pjson)
2. How to save image from url to local disk

Comment: @f0x It's a class, I have provided for ServiceFacade to calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Data Contracts and `DataContractJsonSerializer`:

### References Required:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
```

### Data Contract

```
[DataContract]
internal class GISData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string href;

    [DataMember]
    public int width;

    [DataMember]
    public int height;

    [DataMember]
    public GISDataExtent extent;

    [DataMember]
    public string scale;
}

[DataContract]
internal class GISDataExtent
{
    [DataMember]
    public string xmin;

    [DataMember]
    public string ymin;

    [DataMember]
    public string xmax;

    [DataMember]
    public string ymax;

    [DataMember]
    public GISDataExtentSpatialReference spatialReference;

}

[DataContract]
internal class GISDataExtentSpatialReference
{
    [DataMember]
    public string wkid;
}
```

### Putting it all together and downloading the file:

Pull the JSON String from your URL - Deserialize the object and download your image.

```
WebClient webClient;
webClient = new WebClient();
string json = webClient.DownloadString(@"http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/export?bbox=9153621.1267%2C-644273.9207%2C13435472.9966%2C3637577.9492&bboxSR=&layers=&layerdefs=&size=800%2C600&imageSR=&format=png&transparent=false&dpi=&time=&layerTimeOptions=&f=pjson");

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream((Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)));
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(GISData));
stream.Position = 0;
GISData data = (GISData)ser.ReadObject(stream);
stream.Close();

webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(data.href, "C:/" + data.href.Substring(data.href.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)); //Save only the filename and not the entire URL as a name.
```

Comment: you can do things simpler:
`GISData data = (GISData)ser.ReadObject(@"http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/export?bbox=9153621.1267%2C-644273.9207%2C13435472.9966%2C3637577.9492&bboxSR=&layers=&layerdefs=&size=800%2C600&imageSR=&format=png&transparent=false&dpi=&time=&layerTimeOptions=&f=pjson");`

Comment: also you may omit DataXXX attributes :)

Comment: @the_joric , thanks; `ReadObject`'s best overload seems to be looking for a stream though?

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you need the service request from the server and not from the client; if so a straightforward way would be

```
string json = null;

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/export?bbox=9153621.1267%2C-644273.9207%2C13435472.9966%2C3637577.9492&bboxSR=&layers=&layerdefs=&size=800%2C600&imageSR=&format=png&transparent=false&dpi=&time=&layerTimeOptions=&f=pjson");
HttpWebResponse response = null;

try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    if ((responseStream != null) && responseStream.CanRead)
    {
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    if (response != null)
    {
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

The image can be obtained the same way.

For Json I recommend [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

1. Add Json.NET package (see for reference [How to install JSON.NET using NuGet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444903/how-to-install-json-net-using-nuget))
2. Use the following code:

   ```
   using Newtonsoft.Json;

   ......

   string url = "...";

   var webClient = new WebClient();
   var s = webClient.DownloadString(url);
   dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s);
   var href = ((string) d.href);

   webClient.DownloadFile(href, @"d:\file.png");
   ```

Note that your png file does not exists :)

You may create your POCO class if you want. But if all you need is just download a file — that  may not be needed.