# serializing a class in c#

Tags: c#, json, class, serialization

I was hoping someone could help me with a problem serialzing data into a class please?

I need to send the following json string to a webservice:

{ "arrivalAt": "2012-12-24T20:00:00.0000000Z", "pickup":{"streetName":"Amaliegade","houseNumber":"36","zipCode":"1256","city":"Copenhagen K","country":"DK","lat":55.68,"lng":12.59},  "dropoff":{"streetName":"Amaliegade","houseNumber":"36","zipCode":"1256","city":"Copenhagen K","country":"DK","lat":55.68,"lng":12.59}, "vehicleType": "fourSeaterAny", "comments": "Hello" }'

I put this json string into http://json2csharp.com/ and it generated the following class:

```
public class Pickup
{
public string streetName { get; set; }
public string houseNumber { get; set; }
public string zipCode { get; set; }
public string city { get; set; }
public string country { get; set; }
public double lat { get; set; }
public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Dropoff
{
public string streetName { get; set; }
public string houseNumber { get; set; }
public string zipCode { get; set; }
public string city { get; set; }
public string country { get; set; }
public double lat { get; set; }
public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
public string arrivalAt { get; set; }
public Pickup pickup { get; set; }
public Dropoff dropoff { get; set; }
public string vehicleType { get; set; }
public string comments { get; set; }
}
```

I have managed to do this before but have never had a situation where is there is a class within a class, so to speak. Meaning the "Pickup" & "DropOff" settings...

I am stuck when i try to work out what to do at this line...

```
Booking bookingdetails = new ClickATaxi_Classes.Booking(THIS IS WHERE I WILL PUT THE 17 BITS OF INFORMATION BUT HOW?);
```

I get the feeling there is something i need to do to the class to make it accept arguments but i have no idea where to start and how to send the pickup and dropoff information

can anyone help please?

thanks

Comment: If all your classes are ISerializable the serialization should work properly for contained objects

Comment: Do you mean manually creating the object: Booking bookingdetails = new ClickATaxi_Classes.Booking { arrivalAt = "Something", pickup = new ClickATaxi_Classes.Pickup { streetName = "something else" } };

Comment: @emartel No need for `ISerializable`.

Comment: Why would you make two classes with exact same properties? Wouldn't it be a better solution to add some kind of enum that differentiate Dropoff and Pickup and store them in a single type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should refactor that generated code a little bit

```
public class Location
{
     public string streetName { get; set; }
     public string houseNumber { get; set; }
     public string zipCode { get; set; }
     public string city { get; set; }
     public string country { get; set; }
     public double lat { get; set; }
     public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Booking
{
     public string arrivalAt { get; set; }
     public Location pickup { get; set; }
     public Location dropoff { get; set; }
     public string vehicleType { get; set; }
     public string comments { get; set; }
}
```

There is no need for two classes that mean the same thing.  After that you will just instantiate the booking object.

```
Booking obj = new Booking { arrivalAt = "ARRIVAL", pickup = new Location { streetName = "", houseNumber = "" ... }, dropoff = new Location { streetName = "", houseNumber = "" ...}, vehicleType = "", comments = "" }
```

Next you will serialize to a string, I like [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) but you can use any serializer.
If you want to use JSON.NET you can install it via [Nuget](http://nuget.org/) by [following these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444903/how-to-install-json-net-using-nuget), next add the using statement to the top of your class that will serialize the object:
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

Finally just call JsonConvert

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
```

Here are some links to other serializers:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx
- http://www.servicestack.net/docs/text-serializers/json-csv-jsv-serializers
- http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

Answer (score 0):

[Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/). You need a JSON serializer. Just pick one that you like. The 3 that have been listed work great. And make sure you read [this article](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp) to better understand why you need a JSON serializer.