# WebAPI and EntityFramework *without* LazyLoading

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading, asp.net-web-api

In my current project, I am using *WebAPI* and *EntityFramework* model-first. After some investigation, it appears that I have to use `LazyLoading` in order to load related entities.

I have read in many blogs that using `LazyLoading` in a service can cause performance and serialization problems - so I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this without creating POCO objects?

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as "Accepted" by clicking the green checkbox below its score. If not, please let me know what further info you need, so I can help you overcome the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your question is - use `.Include()`.

As an example: imagine that you have a `Customer` object which has an associated `ReferredBy` object, which references another customer. In your application, you want to return a list of `Customer`s as well as the associated `Customer` who referred each one.

Your WebAPI method might look something like:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Customer> Customers() {
    return db.Customers.OrderBy(c => c.LastName).Top(10);
}
```

When the serializer gets ahold of this, you are liable to run into various errors, which you can read more about [in this article](http://dotnet.learningtree.com/2012/04/03/working-with-the-entity-framework-and-the-web-api/). In essence, though, it comes from 2 things:

1. ProxyCreation / LazyLoading - which is EF-speak for "load the associated objects for my object graph on-demand, only when I ask for them", and
2. Serialization of cycles - which means - `A` refers to `B`, and `B` refers to `A` - so every time I serialize one, I serialize the other again as a child of it. This creates an infinite loop.

I won't get into all of the specifics or the additional problems - I already gave you an article which goes into it in some depth. Instead, here is the way I solve the issue in my applications:

1. Use JSON.net as your serializer. You can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444903/how-to-install-json-net-using-nuget) for instructions on how to set it up in Visual Studio as your project's default serializer (assuming it isn't already)
2. In your `Global.asax` or one of the `.cs` files which is loaded as part of your configuration, use the following settings:

   ```
   config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = 
       Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
   ```

   This tells JSON.net *not* to serialize reference loops.
3. Set the `MergeOption` in your `DataContext` and each of its `Collection` properties to `MergeOption.NoTracking`. In my applications, I do this by editing the `.tt` file which creates the `DataContext`:

   First, find the line that creates the constructor, and change to:

   ```
   MergeOption _defaultMergeOption = MergeOption.AppendOnly;

   public <#=code.Escape(container)#>() : this("name=<#=container.Name#>") { }
   public <#=code.Escape(container)#>(String connectionString) : base(connectionString) {
   <# if (!loader.IsLazyLoadingEnabled(container)) { #>
       this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   <# } #>
       this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
       _defaultMergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
   }
   ```

   Find the line that starts with:

   ```
   <#  foreach (var entitySet in container.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>()) { #>
   ```

   Now edit the next few lines to say:

   ```
   <#  foreach (var entitySet in container.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>()) { #>
   <#= Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(entitySet)#> ObjectQuery<<#=typeMapper.GetTypeName(entitySet.ElementType)#>> <#=code.Escape(entitySet)#> {
       get {
           var set = (((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext).CreateObjectSet<<#=typeMapper.GetTypeName(entitySet.ElementType)#>>();
           set.MergeOption = _defaultMergeOption;

           return set;
       }
   }
   <#  }
   ```

   What this does, is give you a constructor for your `DataContext` which can default all of the collections to `MergeOption.NoTracking`, and automatically disable `ProxyCreation` and `LazyLoading`. When you create an instance of your `DataContext` to pull from, you can now simply say:

   ```
   var db = new MyDataContext("ConnectionStringGoesHere");
   ```

Given the above, your new WebAPI method becomes as simple as:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Customer> Customers() {
    return db.Customers.Include("ReferredBy")
             .OrderBy(c => c.LastName).Top(10);
}
```

The `.Include()` will load the child-record as part of the initial SQL statement (one hit to the database in total), and the Serializer will ignore the back-references, allowing you to produce JSON similar to:

```
[{
    Id: 1,
    FirstName: 'Frank',
    LastName: 'Abba',
    ReferredBy: {
        Id: 4,
        FirstName: 'Bob',
        LastName: 'Jones',
        ReferredBy: null
    }
 }, {
    Id: 4,
    FirstName: 'Bob',
    LastName: 'Jones',
    ReferredBy: null
 }
}]
```