# Json.net installation not working

Tags: c#, json.net

Simple. I installed Json.net using NuGet and when in the code I typed JsonConvert I excepted the auto complete options to kick in, but it didn't. I just typed the whole function by my self and got a bunch of errors saying it doesn't exist. I tried restarting Visual Studio but same results. What step am I missing?

Comment: See this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444903/how-to-install-json-net-using-nuget

Comment: Probably "using" the namespace. But that's hard to tell.

Comment: `using Newtonsoft.Json`?

Comment: What am I suppose to add in the using section? I'm lost. Oh wait I figured it out. Thank you! didn't realize I had to add it.

Comment: See, as you said: Simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a couple of ways.

Via the "Solution Explorer"

Simply right-click the "References" folder and select "Manage NuGet Packages..."
Once that window comes up click on the option labeled "Online" in the left most part of the dialog.
Then in the search bar in the upper right type "json.net"
Click "Install" and you're done.
Via the "Package Manager Console"

Open the console. "View" > "Other Windows" > "Package Manager Console"
Then type the following:
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
For more info on how to use the "Package Manager Console" check out the [nuget docs](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have forgot to include the following namespace:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```