# Application canot load dll

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote simple console application.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new HttpClient().PostAsJsonAsync("URL", "Text");
}
```

And added `System.Net.Http` and `System.Net.Http.Formatting` referenes to project.

I get this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred
>   in System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: What IDE? Did you check the libraries' locations and expected locations?

Comment: Do you have the Newtonsoft.Json dependency?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference) and msdn.blog link in accepted answer.

Comment: I`m using Visual Studio 2013. Newtonsoft.Json not mentioned on MSDN, in the description of the method, now I installed JSON.net package via nuget, but get the same exeption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Newtonsoft.Json" is an assembly from the JSON.NET Nuget Package. Follow the steps in the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444903/how-to-install-json-net-using-nuget).

After successfully installing the package, you can add a reference to Newtonsoft.Json, just as you did for "System.Net.Http".

Comment: Reference to Newtonsoft.Json was added automatically when I install package. Still same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the references to "System.Net.Http", "System.Net.Http.Formatting" and Newtonsoft.Json have Copy Local set to True.  On my Visual Studio 2013, when I added a reference to System.Net.Http, the default for Copy Local was false.

You could instead use nuget to add the package for System.Net.Http and Json.Net.  I didn't find a nuget package for System.Net.Http.Formatting.

Comment: I find Microsoft.Net.Http in nuget, and install it, after that, it worked. A little unclear, but the problem is solved.

Comment: The System.Net.Http was likely built using a different version of Newtonsoft.Json, which had a different [stong name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
When you add the package for [Newtonsoft.Json Nuget adds assembly binding redirects](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2012/04/04/json-net-strong-naming-and-assembly-version-numbers).  A better description of Assembly Binding Redirects is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You use it to point strong named assembly references to newer versions of those assemblies.