# Editing JSON using JSONPath

Tags: c#, json, jsonpath

Hello SO community :)!

I want to create method which will let user to edit (or add) JSON specific value or object (located in JSON by JSONPath). Below simple example what is on my mind. User always enters JSON, JSONPath and value/object to change. I'm using Json.NET library.

Method **input** {json, jsonpath, valuetoedit} || **output** {new json as string}

Example input:

```
{ "store": {
    "book": [ 
      { "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  }
}
```

**Example JSONPath:**

```
$.store.book[*].author
```

**Example value to change:**

```
NewAuthorSpecifiedByUser
```

**Output** - new JSON where all authors will be changed to 'NewAuthorSpecifiedByUser'.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to take a `code-first` approach, and deserialize the JSON into an object graph, modify the object graph, then serialize back to JSON? Especially with larger and more complex JSON, I'd think it would be faster to update as `POCO` rather than trying to update json by path. I mean, you have all of C# at your disposal as opposed to some dev using measly javascript (joking)!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 3rd party package [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) allows this to be done easily:

1. Parse the JSON into a [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) hierarchy of [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) tokens.
2. Select JSON values to modify via [`SelectTokens`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) using a query string in [JSONPath syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).
3. Using [`JToken.Replace()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Replace.htm) replace the selected values with the new values.  A new value can be serialized directly to a `JToken` using [`JToken.FromObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject.htm).

Thus:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JToken ReplacePath<T>(this JToken root, string path, T newValue)
    {
        if (root == null || path == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        foreach (var value in root.SelectTokens(path).ToList())
        {
            if (value == root)
                root = JToken.FromObject(newValue);
            else
                value.Replace(JToken.FromObject(newValue));
        }

        return root;
    }    

    public static string ReplacePath<T>(string jsonString, string path, T newValue)
    {
        return JToken.Parse(jsonString).ReplacePath(path, newValue).ToString();
    }    
}
```

Then use it like:

```
var newJsonAuthorString = JsonExtensions.ReplacePath(jsonString, @"$.store.book[*].author", "NewAuthorSpecifiedByUser");
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f3q04u).  If you are going to allow the user to do a series of edits, it will likely be more efficient to keep your JSON in a `JToken` hierarchy permanently rather that repeatedly converting from and to a string representation.

See also [How to install JSON.NET using NuGet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444903/how-to-install-json-net-using-nuget).

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!