# How do I easily modify *any* property of C# deserialized .json?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

config/data.json

```
{
    "background": false,
    "title": "XYZ",
    "object1": {
        "something1": -1,
        "something2": "auto",
        "something3": false,
        "something4": true,
    },
    "object2": {
        "something1": true,
        "something2": true,
        "something3": false,
        "something4": [
            [5,0],
            [4,1]
        ]
    },
    "object3": [
        {
            "something1": null,
            "something2": null,
            "something3": "someString",
            "something4": "someString",
        }
    ],
}
```

program.cs

```
// Necessary classes for JSON de-serialization
`public class Object1
    {
        public int something1 { get; set; }
        public string something2 { get; set; }
        public bool something3 { get; set; }
        public bool something4 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Object2
    {
        public bool something1 { get; set; }
        public bool something2 { get; set; }
        public bool something3 { get; set; }
        public IList<IList<int>> something4 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Object3
    {
        public object something1 { get; set; }
        public object something2 { get; set; }
        public string something3 { get; set; }
        public string something4 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public bool background { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public Object1 object1 { get; set; }
        public Object2 object2 { get; set; }
        public IList<Object3> object3 { get; set; }
    }
```

//Methods to modify all the JSON objects

```
        private readonly static string rigJsonPath = 
        Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, Path.Combine("config", "data.json"));

        public static Example ReadAndDeserialize()
        { 
            string json = File.ReadAllText(rigJsonPath);
            Example ex = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Rig.Xmrig>(json)!;
            return ex;   
        }
        public static void SerializeAndWrite(Example ex)
        {
            string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(ex);
            File.WriteAllText(rigJsonPath, json);
        }
        public static void ModifyXmrProperty(Example ex, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
        {
            switch (propertyName)
            {
                case "background":
                    ex.background = (bool)propertyValue;
                    break;
                case "title":
                    ex.title = (string)propertyValue;
                    break;
                case "object1.something1":
                    ex.object1!.something1 = (int)propertyValue;
                    break;
                   // etc, cannot do it forever though
            }
        }
```

I want to be able to modify any property/object of JSON through a method in C#.

Ideally this operation would take parameters, deserialize JSON, modify fields, serialize back to JSON and overwrite the file.

The existance of helper methods (ReadAndDeserialize() and SerializeAndWrite()) come from my poor attempt at breaking the task into smaller operations, for simplicity.

To sum it up, I'd like to create a *universal* method to be able to modify any property/object/nested object of JSON through C# method.

I've been trying to look up some solutions online but with no results.
Obviously I cannot do switch statement for millions of objects/nested objects - this is just the 'monkey way' of dealing with this.

Comment: I'm not quite following. Can you start your "question" with a succinct paragraph that explains what you are trying to accomplish and why? Saying _"Obviously I cannot do switch statement for millions of objects/nested objects"_ doesn't help if people don't grasp what you are trying to do (and what these millions of things might be)

Comment: Take a look at JSONPath, allows you to manipulate the JSON doc without deserializing it to typed objects.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35804255/17536565

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
public static string YourNameForMethod(string originalJson, string nameOfTheObjectYouWantToChange, string nameOfThePropertyYouWantToChange, object newValue)
{
   // parse your json
   var jsonNode = JsonNode.Parse(originalJson);
   // gets your object from your json
   var objectNode = jsonNode[nameOfTheObjectYouWantToChange];

   //Do null check of objectNode here

   // set ne value to property
   objectNode[nameOfThePropertyYouWantToChange] = JsonValue.Create(newValue); //maybe another null check here

   //return new Json
   return jsonNode.ToJsonString()
}
```