# Using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to deserialize Json

Tags: c#, .net, json, xamarin

I have the following string that I want to convert into object `City`. This doesn't work but throws:

> Could not resolve type: global::Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Jsonstring:

```
{"result":{"id_city":"XX","city_name":"XXXX","city_province":"BW","city_country":"DE","city_zipcode":null,"city_gps_lat":"XXXXXX","city_gps_lng":"XXXXXX","city_gps_geohash":"XXXXXX","city_image":"XXXXXX","distance":11111}}
```

City class:

```
 public class City
 {
      [JsonProperty("id_city")]
      public string id_city { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("city_name")]
      public string city_name { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("city_province")]
      public string city_province { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("city_country")]
      public string city_country { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("city_zipcode")]
      public string city_zipcode { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("city_gps_lat")]
      public string city_gps_lat { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("city_gps_lng")]
      public string city_gps_lng { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("city_gps_geohash")]
      public string city_gps_geohash { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("city_image")]
      public string city_image { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("distance")]
      public string distance { get; set; }
}
```

Method call:

```
City stadt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<City>(Jsonstring);
```

*installed Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.3 over NuGet*

Comment: Have you added a reference to the Json.Net dlls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install JSON.NET using NuGet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444903/how-to-install-json-net-using-nuget)

Comment: @Liam yes i added Newtonsoft.Json and also using it

Comment: That seems unlikely....

Comment: i added the version 8.0.3

Comment: One of your assemblies does not have the correct reference. Check them all and ensure everything that needs to access Json.Net has the assembly reference added. It'll be whichever one is erroring. This is pretty basic stuff..

Comment: @Liam i checked all References and they exist this message also only comes in Debug mode, after executing this code the object is still empty but it didnt break the app

Comment: @Liam Could be the problem the "result" in front of my json string?

Comment: the `json` doesn't correspond to the type you have created. You'll need another wrapper like -`public class RootObject
{
    public City result { get; set; }
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string represents a class with a `result` property of `City` type.

```
public class YourResultClass
{
    public City result { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize the string to `YourResultClass`.

```
YourResultClass stadt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourResultClass>(Jsonstring);
```

You can use [JSonEditorOnline](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) to check what your json string represents.