# Put JSON data into c# datatable

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am trying to deserialise some JSON that I get back from an API so that I can loop through an array of county names and add the information to a datatable in C#. However I am receiving following error at the first hurdle when I try and deserialise it:

> error: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'DPDJSONLibrary.DPD_JSON+LOCR_Data[]'.

The provider of the API provides an example of the JSON response as follows:

```
{
    "error": null,
    "data":[{
        "country": [{
            "countryCode":"GB",
            "countryName":"United Kingdom",
            "internalCode":"UK",
            "isEUCountry":false,
            "isLiabilityAllowed":false,
            "isoCode":"826",
            "isPostcodeRequired":false,
            "liabilityMax":15000
        }]
    }]
}
```

A sample of the JSON data I am getting back from the API is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "country":[
            {
                "countryCode":"PM",
                "countryName":"St Pierre & Miquilon",
                "isoCode":"666",
                "isEUCountry":false,
                "isLiabilityAllowed":true,
                "liabilityMax":15000,
                "isPostcodeRequired":true
            },
            {
                "countryCode":"SR",
                "countryName":"Suriname",
                "isoCode":"740",
                "isEUCountry":false,
                "isLiabilityAllowed":true,
                "liabilityMax":15000,
                "isPostcodeRequired":true
            },
            {
                "countryCode":"SZ",
                "countryName":"Swaziland",
                "isoCode":"748",
                "isEUCountry":false,
                "isLiabilityAllowed":true,
                "liabilityMax":15000,
                "isPostcodeRequired":true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried to make some classes to put the JSON in as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// List Of Countries Response object.
/// </summary>
public class LOCR
{
    public LOCR_Error error { get; set; }
    public LOCR_Data[] data { get; set; }
}

public class LOCR_Error
{
    public string errorAction { get; set; }
    public string errorCode { get; set; }
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
    public string errorObj { get; set; }
    public string errorType { get; set; }
}

public class LOCR_Data
{
    public LOCR_Data_Country[] country { get; set; }
}

public class LOCR_Data_Country
{
    public string countryCode { get; set; }
    public string countryName { get; set; }
    public string internalCode { get; set; }
    public bool isEUCountry { get; set; }
    public bool isLiabilityAllowed { get; set; }
    public string isoCode { get; set; }
    public bool isPostcodeRequired { get; set; }
    public int liabilityMax { get; set; }
}
```

When I get the JSON back as a string, I am trying to use the Newtonsoft (plugin?) to put it into my classes using:

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
DPD_JSON.LOCR DPDCountries = new DPD_JSON.LOCR();
DPDCountries = ser.Deserialize<DPD_JSON.LOCR>(data);
```

It is the last line above that is generating the error. I suspect I've written my classes wrong that I am trying to deserialise the JSON in to - can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: This should work just fine, can you try with `List<LOCR_Data>` instead of `LOCR_Data[]` ?

Comment: Your Json is not valid - the last element in the array has a comma after it.

Comment: I have removed the last comma from the data in my post - that's my fault. The data I get back from the API contains hundreds of lines so I removed most of them so the post wasn't too long. I missed the last comma.

Answer (score 0):

`Deserialize` will return a list and not an array, So your `LOCR_Data_Country` should be of type `List` and not array:

```
    public class LOCR_Data
    {
        public List<LOCR_Data_Country> country { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The return type depends on the library used. Newtonsoft for example can return array types as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's a **HUGE** difference between the two example JSON strings you've shown. Mainly the first one is an array : `"data":[ ... ]` and the second one is an object `"data:{ ... }`. These two are not interchangeable so you have to stick to either one of those. If the thing you're getting back from the API is an object instead you should rewrite your model to be :

```
public class LOCR
{
    public LOCR_Error error { get; set; }
    // object here since "data": { ... }
    public LOCR_Data data { get; set; }
}
```

And as you move further with the JSON you can see that `LOCR_Data.country` is in fact an array in both cases `"country": [ ... ]` so you can stick with the current implementation of `LOCR_Data` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using :

```
YourResultClass object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourResultClass>(Jsonstring);
```

See the answer of this [Using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to deserialize Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41441089/using-jsonconvert-deserializeobject-to-deserialize-json)

OR

```
dynamic data = Json.Decode(json);
```

You can refer this [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object/3806407#3806407) for further assistance