# Json data not converting to List

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a json data which was not serialized properly.
I have attached the expected and bad one.

I need to handle the bad json, get in a right format

Expected

```
"channels": {
    "heart-rate": {
        "events": {
            "type": "Project.Model.ChannelEvents.HeartRateChannelEvent, Project, Version=1.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            "structure": [
                "beatsPerMinute",
                "offset"
            ],
            "list": [
                [
                    40,
                    0
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    "location": {
        "events": {
            "type": "Project.Model.ChannelEvents.LocationChannelEvent, Project, Version=1.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            "structure": [
                "latitude",
                "longitude",
                "offset"
            ],
            "list": [
                [
                    0.0,
                    0.0,
                    0
                ]
            ]
        }

    }
}
```

**badjson**
This is the bad json data which needs to be formatted, in a console application

```
"channels": {
    "heart-rate": {
        "events": {
            "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Project.Model.Activity+Channel+Event, Project]], mscorlib",
            "$values": [{
                    "$type": "Project.Model.ChannelEvents.HeartRateChannelEvent, Project",
                    "beatsPerMinute": 40,
                    "offset": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "location": {
        "events": {
            "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Project.Model.Activity+Channel+Event, Project]], mscorlib",
            "$values": [{
                    "$type": "Project.Model.ChannelEvents.LocationChannelEvent, Project",
                    "latitude": 0.0,
                    "longitude": 0.0,
                    "offset": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly check the first posted JSON data,it contains errors.

Comment: what is bad about your bad json?

Comment: @victor- if you look into the first, where i have structure and list- i see those missing in bad data

Comment: Do you have the code you serialized it with?

Comment: It looks like the two JSON strings were serialized using different serializers; the easiest thing would be to find out what the right serializer to use is, and then to deserialize the 'bad' JSON using the serializer that understands it, and re-serialize it using the 'good' serializer. The first JSON looks pretty non-standard so if it was custom code, than you'll need to replicate or reuse that code.

Comment: public string Type { get; set; }

            public IList<Channel.Event> Events { get; set; }

            public abstract class Event
            {
                public uint Offset { get; set; }
            }
        }

Comment: Both your good and bad JSON are syntactically invalid: they are missing outer braces `{` and `}`.  Upload to http://jsonlint.com/ and you will see an error reported.  Is your JSON actually wrong in this manner, or is this a typo in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, both your input and output JSON are syntactically invalid: they are missing outer braces `{` and `}`.  For the remainder of this answer, I'm going to assume this is a typo in the question.

Assuming you have not done so already, you could install [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4444903/3744182) and then use [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to load and modify your JSON.  Using this approach avoids the need to define c# types that perfectly match your JSON.

Your input JSON has two problems:

- The tokens `"channels.heart-rate.events"` and `"channels.location.events"` are arrays of objects for which [Json.NET type information](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) has been included.  (It is clear from the presence of the `"$type"` property that the JSON was originally generated using Json.NET)

  What you want instead is for these arrays to be reformatted into a single object that contains the item type, an array of item property names, and an array of array of item property values.
- The type information has been formatted using [`TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_TypeNameAssemblyFormat.htm).  You want to add assembly information, converting to [`FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt9xha1h) format.

Both of these can be corrected using LINQ-to-JSON.  Say you have two streams, `Stream inputStream` and `Stream outputStream` corresponding to a stream with the JSON to be fixed and a stream in which to store the fixed JSON.  Then, introduce the following utility methods:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    const string JsonTypeName = @"$type";
    const string JsonValuesName = @"$values";

    public static void ReformatCollections(Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream, IEnumerable<string> paths, Func<string, string> typeNameMapper, Formatting formatting)
    {
        var root = JToken.Load(new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(inputStream)) { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None });
        root = ReformatCollections(root, paths, typeNameMapper);

        var writer = new StreamWriter(outputStream);
        var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer) { Formatting = formatting };

        root.WriteTo(jsonWriter);
        jsonWriter.Flush();
        writer.Flush();
    }

    public static JToken ReformatCollections(JToken root, IEnumerable<string> paths, Func<string, string> typeNameMapper)
    {
        foreach (var path in paths)
        {
            var token = root.SelectToken(path);
            var newToken = token.ReformatCollection(typeNameMapper);
            if (root == token)
                root = newToken;
        }

        return root;
    }

    public static JToken ReformatCollection(this JToken value, Func<string, string> typeNameMapper)
    {
        if (value == null || value.Type == JTokenType.Null)
            return value;

        var array = value as JArray;
        if (array == null)
            array = value[JsonValuesName] as JArray;
        if (array == null)
            return value;

        // Extract the item $type and ordered set of properties.
        string type = null;
        var properties = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var item in array)
        {
            if (item.Type == JTokenType.Null)
                continue;
            var obj = item as JObject;
            if (obj == null)
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Item \"{0}\" was not a JObject", obj.ToString(Formatting.None)));
            var objType = (string)obj[JsonTypeName];
            if (objType != null && type == null)
                type = objType;
            else if (objType != null && type != null)
            {
                if (type != objType)
                    throw new JsonSerializationException("Too many item types.");
            }
            foreach (var property in obj.Properties().Where(p => p.Name != JsonTypeName))
            {
                if (!properties.ContainsKey(property.Name))
                    properties.Add(property.Name, properties.Count);
            }
        }
        var propertyList = properties.OrderBy(p => p.Value).Select(p => p.Key).ToArray();
        var newValue = new JObject();
        if (type != null)
            newValue["type"] = JToken.FromObject(typeNameMapper(type));
        newValue["structure"] = JToken.FromObject(propertyList);
        newValue["list"] = JToken.FromObject(array
            .Select(o => (o.Type == JTokenType.Null ? o : propertyList.Where(p => o[p] != null).Select(p => o[p]))));
        if (value.Parent != null)
            value.Replace(newValue);
        return newValue;
    }
}
```

Then, at the top level of your console method, you can fix your JSON as follows:

```
    Func<string, string> typeNameMapper = (t) =>
        {
            if (!t.EndsWith(", Version=1.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"))
                t = t + ", Version=1.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";
            return t;
        };
    var paths = new[]
        {
            "channels.heart-rate.events",
            "channels.location.events"
        };
    JsonExtensions.ReformatCollections(inputStream, outputStream, paths, typeNameMapper, Formatting.Indented);
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iferpX).

Comment: Let me try this.  This looks helpful

Comment: +1 The values are converting but i am not able to deserialize the output json, when i change the latitude nad longitude values @dbc

Comment: @kishore - then you might want to ask a second question, or otherwise provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your new problem.  As it is your question is about transforming one JSON format to another, and doesn't really involve deserialization at all.

Comment: link to my new question @dbc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43171814/unable-to-deserialize-my-json

Comment: I just have another one, Can i take our type,structure,list for one path and leave it for other path byt $type ,$values should be transformed anyway

Answer (score 0):

Use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) to Serialize and Deserialize your JSON