# Is there a way to serialize collection to JSON or XML compactly

Tags: c#, json, xml, serialization

I have a collection of plain entities like this:

```
class Element
{
    public int LongNameOfPropertyA { get; set;}
    public int LongNameOfPropertyB { get; set;}
    public string LongNameOfPropertyC { get; set;}
}
```

By default it serializes to something like this:

```
[{
   "LongNameOfPropertyA": "1",
   "LongNameOfPropertyB": "2",
   "LongNameOfPropertyC": "bla"
},
{
   "LongNameOfPropertyA": "2",
   "LongNameOfPropertyB": "3",
   "LongNameOfPropertyC": "asdf"
}]
```

My question is there a option to serialize like this:

```
[{
    "entityName": "Element",
    "columns": [ 
        { "columnName": "LongNameOfPropertyA" },
        { "columnName": "LongNameOfPropertyB" },
        { "columnName": "LongNameOfPropertyC" }],
    "data": [
        { "columnData": ["1", "2"]},
        { "columnData": ["2", "3"]},
        { "columnData": ["bla", "asdf"]}]
}]
```

the xml solution will be also acceptable

Comment: No, because your target JSON is invalid.

Comment: @Smartis, please hint me on mistake. Is this imposible at all, or I just mistype somewhere?

Comment: @Smartis, Thanks, now Is this possible?

Comment: Of course, restructure your classes accordingly or write your own parser.

Comment: @Smartis, Is something parser can be extended with some plugin?

Comment: For JSON, `StructuredListConverter<T>` from [Unable to deserialize my json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43173427/3744182) should probably work for you with minor changes.  Is that answer sufficient, or do you need something specific?

Comment: @dbc, Thank you so much! This is what I dreamed about

Comment: @gabba - you're welcome.  I went ahead and marked this as a duplicate.