# Ajax success function not receive data

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Below is webmethod of my web form which is returning a List of data and it works fine:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<SalesInvoiceFinalCalculationEntity> salesInvoiceFinalCalculaiton(string InvoiceNo)
{
    List<SalesInvoiceFinalCalculationEntity> list = new List<SalesInvoiceFinalCalculationEntity>();
    list = SalesInvoiceManager1.salesInvoiceFinalCalculaiton(InvoiceNo);
    return list;
}
```

But in below Ajax function, I can't retrieve the data. When I bind data to textbox in ajax success function, it displays Undefined text in Html textBox.

```
function salesInvoiceFinalCalculaiton() {        

    var InvoiceNo = $("#txt_InvoiceNo").val();
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/AjaxRequestToServer.aspx/salesInvoiceFinalCalculaiton", //URI   
        data: "{InvoiceNo:'" + InvoiceNo + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            document.getElementById("txtinvoicevalue").value=(data.totalprice);
            document.getElementById("txtTotalDiscount").value = data.discountamt;
            document.getElementById("txtTotalTaxableValue").value = data.taxableamt;
            document.getElementById("txtTotalCGST").value = data.cgstamt;
            document.getElementById("txtTotalSGST").value = data.sgstamt;
            document.getElementById("txtGrandTotal").value = data.grandtotal;

        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            if (xhr.statusText == "Invalid Request") {
                sessionStorage.clear();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is Data Layer and the stored procedure:

```
 public static List<SalesInvoiceFinalCalculationEntity> salesInvoiceFinalCalculaiton(string InvoiceNo)
        {
            try
            {


                List<SalesInvoiceFinalCalculationEntity> SalesInvoiceFinalCalculation = new List<SalesInvoiceFinalCalculationEntity>();

                DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Util.ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "sp_salesInvoiceFinalCalculaiton",
                    new SqlParameter("@InvoiceNo", InvoiceNo));

                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    SalesInvoiceFinalCalculationEntity list = new SalesInvoiceFinalCalculationEntity(dr);
                    SalesInvoiceFinalCalculation.Add(list);
                }
                return SalesInvoiceFinalCalculation;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

And this is my entity Class:

```
public class SalesInvoiceFinalCalculationEntity
    {
        public int InvoiceNo { get; set; }
        float totalprice { get; set; }
        float discountamt { get; set; }
        float taxableamt { get; set; }
        float cgstamt { get; set; }
        float sgstamt { get; set; }
        float grandtotal { get; set; }
        public SalesInvoiceFinalCalculationEntity() { }
        public SalesInvoiceFinalCalculationEntity(DataRow dr)
        {
            InvoiceNo = Convert.ToInt32(dr["InvoiceNo"]);
            totalprice = float.Parse(dr["totalprice"].ToString());
            discountamt = float.Parse(dr["discountamt"].ToString());
            taxableamt = float.Parse(dr["taxableamt"].ToString());
            cgstamt = float.Parse(dr["cgstamt"].ToString());
            sgstamt = float.Parse(dr["sgstamt"].ToString());
            grandtotal = float.Parse(dr["grandtotal"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

why is data is not received in success function!

Comment: Do you have any errors ? It is hitting your method ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai yes it hits method and method returns list if data. i dint get any errors. but it displays "Undefined" Text in textBox. Its not displays Actual Value In textbox.

Comment: Have you tried success: function (data.d)? If memory serves, when using webmethods like you are the object is actually in 'data.d' and not just 'data'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved it. I forgot to mentioned

`Public`

in

`SalesInvoiceFinalCalculationEntity`

entity all variables and `document.getElementById("txtinvoicevalue").value=(data.d[0].totalprice);` this should be instead of

`document.getElementById("txtinvoicevalue").value=(data.totalprice);`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, using `async: false` it is a bad practice because it's **freeze** your window during to your request. **Don't use it.**

The issue is that you have to return a `json` object from your `server-side` method in order to receive **response** in success **callback** function of your ajax method.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string salesInvoiceFinalCalculaiton(string InvoiceNo)
{
        List<SalesInvoiceFinalCalculationEntity> list = new List<SalesInvoiceFinalCalculationEntity>();
        list = SalesInvoiceManager1.salesInvoiceFinalCalculaiton(InvoiceNo);
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
}
```

Web requests work with `json` format.

Comment: now it shows error "JsonConvert dose not exist in current context"

Comment: Then please add reference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444903/how-to-install-json-net-using-nuget. It's a nuget package

Comment: nuget packege error is resolved but data not displaying in Textbox.

Comment: @DinkarVeer, Use `console.log(data)` in success function and tell me what you received.

Comment: I resolved It @alexandru-ionut mihai Thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that you're trying to send a Java Class to your JavaScript file. You can only send simple data types numbers, letters. As I understand, you're trying to access the member variables of SalesInvoiceFinalCalculationEntity.

If that's the case, you need to send it as a JSON object and get the data like this and then parse it.

The idea behind AJAX is to make the experience for the user better by **not** freezing the website using asynchronous requests. By calling the AJAX call with

> async: false

removes the idea behind AJAX. You could then simply make a normal call to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

> https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Serialize your list and return it as a string.

Then, in your javascript:

```
success: function (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    document.getElementById("txtinvoicevalue").value=(data.totalprice);
    document.getElementById("txtTotalDiscount").value = data.discountamt;
    document.getElementById("txtTotalTaxableValue").value = data.taxableamt;
    document.getElementById("txtTotalCGST").value = data.cgstamt;
    document.getElementById("txtTotalSGST").value = data.sgstamt;
    document.getElementById("txtGrandTotal").value = data.grandtotal;

},
```

Comment: What is Service.svc?

Comment: Which kind of webservice are you using? It's WCF

Comment: actuly its just simple asp.net webform which i called by ajax.

Comment: i dont know.. how to do it.. plz specify

Comment: data: '{invoicefinalcalc:' + JSON.stringify(invoicefinalcalc) + '}',   Like this?

Comment: Edited my answer, this is how to do it ^^

Comment: Now its not display anything in textbox

Comment: try a console.out(data)

Comment: I can't, do a console.out of data content, it will show you the data object, i think that yoi wrote wrong data properties ^^

Comment: @MarcoSalerno, `InvoiceNo` is a primitive type, string, you do not need to strigify it.Also, if you return json from server-side method in the success callback data will be parsed automatically.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Please See Edits in question

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Yes I tried But It shows error in ActioResult and json(list)

Comment: Types or namespace name 'ActionResult' Could not be found and same error for salesInvoiceFinalCalculaiton also

Comment: @DinkarVeer, have a look to my answer. I updated it. I forgot it's a webforms application

Answer (score 0):

Try
`success: function (data.d)` rather than `success: function (data)`. If I recall when using webmethods the return object is within data.d and not simply data.

Also, despite what other answers say. When using the `[webmethod]` attribute and jquery ajax, you do not have to convert your response object to json. It will do so automatically.

Comment: it gives error to '.d' error-: expected'{' and expected';'

Comment: it looks like you are returning a list, so you would also need to loop through your response object? What does your object look like in the browser dev tools? Can you post that please?