# Ajax success function not receiving data ASP.NET MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-ajax

I can add the data to the database correctly, but Ajax success function is not working. I always get the error function :

View:

```
<div id="dvform">
    <!-- some data-->
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="btnsubmit" />
</div>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnsubmit").click(function () {
                addAppointment();
            });
        });
            function addAppointment (){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/FuelerAppointments/Create',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: $("dvform").val(),

                    success: function (data) {
                      swal("Done!", "The appointment was saved successfully!", "success");
                    },
                    error: function (data) {

                         swal("Error deleting!", "Please try again", "error");
                     },
                });
            }
```

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FuelerAppointment fuelerAppointment)
{
    return Json(fuelerAppointment, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: maybe help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239013/ajax-success-function-not-receive-data

Answer (score 0):

First you should change `dataType: "html",` to `dataType: "json",`
and create FuelerAppointment object before the $.ajax():

```
        var fuelerAppointment = {};  
        fuelerAppointment.Name = $("#Name").val();
```

and then the data in ajax method

`data: '{fuelerAppointment: ' + JSON.stringify(fuelerAppointment) + '}',`

For more information check this link [Using AJAX In ASP.NET MVC](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/using-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

change `dataType: "html"` to `dataType: "json"`

---

and in data properties should you write like this

```
var model = {
     prop1: prop1Value,
     prop2: prop2Value,
     ...
};
data: {fuelerAppointment: model}
```

***Or***

```
data: JSON.stringify({
   fuelerAppointment: {
        prop1: prop1Value,
        prop2: prop2Value,
        ...
   }
})
```

> **Notes**: the fuelerAppointment object should behave a sem proprieties in C# class