# Parsing a JSON dictionary that contains the same key with different casing

Tags: c#, json

I have a problem;
I would to know if there is a method to parse json file without having a unique format. So it may have different attributes but all of them contain the attribute Status but it can be in double.

```
  {
  "requestid": "1111",
  "message": "db",
  "status": "OK",
  "data": [
    {
      "Status": "OK", // this one I would to test first to read the other attributes
      "fand": "",
      "nalDate": "",
      "price": 1230000,
      "status": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can parse a Json string to a dictionnary.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking... Maybe you could look at `JToken.Parse` (Newtonsoft Json library) and navigate the tree that way?

Comment: Are you trying to ask whether you can parse a *dictionary* when it contains both `Status` and `status` keys? I'm not sure that's valid JSON to begin with

Comment: As a dictionnary ! I think it was a dump question :) Thanks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this Json is perfectly valid as the RFC 4627, RFC 7159 and ECMA-404 say's  (you can validate it here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: @fruggiero I checked the standard too. It says nothing about casing, except that *the implementations should agree* so anything goes. C# dictionaries are case-sensitive by default, property names as well, so this *should* deserialize without issue, at least for dictionaries.

Comment: Just tried it now, Json.NET can deserialize directly to an object that has a `Status` and a `status` property.

Comment: as a dictionary?

Comment: I have to notice that data may be an array of data and sometime not !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

```
Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

And create the class Data with the interesting data inside the json

Comment: The problem is data does not have a unique structure !

Comment: I understood it, that's why this library is great, it doesn't care at all ^^

Comment: No, I tested before it does not work if the value of json data does not match with structure of the class, the deserialisation will be fail.

Comment: I'm sure that you are wrong i use it for the same purpose, if it doesn't find anything it just doesn't populate the property

Comment: because it may be an array of object and it can be not !

Comment: So use a list ^^

Comment: and it can be fall in the second Status rather than the first one

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: It may have a 2 status in the data entry and it get the last one not the first one, I tested right now

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: string Status { get; set; }
        string status { get; set; }

Comment: i don't have any problem, just tested ^^

Comment: Looking at your pic i can't see a problem, it's getting the status

Comment: Ah u put twice status then it may have a 3 status and it will get the last two element

Comment: I suppose you don't understand, i give up :\

Comment: maybe I don't see it clearyl right now Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Anyway this is the solution to your problem focus on it, good luck ^^

Answer (score 1):

The defacto standard Json serializer for .NET is [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) ([How to install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444903/how-to-install-json-net-using-nuget)). You can parse the Json into an object graph and work on that in any order you like:

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    using System;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var text = @"{
                'requestid': '1111',
                'message': 'db',
                'status': 'OK',
                'data': [
                {
                    'Status': 'OK', // this one I would to test first to read the other attributes
                    'fand': '',
                    'nalDate': '',
                    'price': 1230000,
                    'status': 2
                }
                ]
            }";

            var json = JObject.Parse(text);

            Console.WriteLine(json.SelectToken("data[0].Status").Value<string>());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```