# How to convert Dynamic JSON

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to convert some data from one JSON format to another, but running into to some issues.

```
[
[{"Key":"entity_id","Value":"1"},{"Key":"CustomerName","Value":"Test1"},{"Key":"AccountNumber","Value":"ACC17-001"},{"Key":"CustomerType","Value":"Direct Sale"}],
[{"Key":"entity_id","Value":"2"},{"Key":"CustomerName","Value":"Test2"},{"Key":"AccountNumber","Value":"ACC17-002"},{"Key":"CustomerType","Value":"Direct Sale"}],
[{"Key":"entity_id","Value":"3"},{"Key":"CustomerName","Value":"Test3"},{"Key":"AccountNumber","Value":"ACC17-003"},{"Key":"CustomerType","Value":"Direct Sale"}],
[{"Key":"entity_id","Value":"4"},{"Key":"CustomerName","Value":"Test4"},{"Key":"AccountNumber","Value":"ACC17-004"},{"Key":"CustomerType","Value":"Direct Sale"}],
[{"Key":"entity_id","Value":"5"},{"Key":"CustomerName","Value":"Test5"},{"Key":"AccountNumber","Value":"ACC17-005"},{"Key":"CustomerType","Value":"Invoice"}],
[{"Key":"entity_id","Value":"6"},{"Key":"CustomerName","Value":"Test6"},{"Key":"AccountNumber","Value":"ACC17-006"},{"Key":"CustomerType","Value":"Invoice"}]
]
```

Into this:

```
[
{"entity_id":"1","CustomerName":"Test1","AccountNumber":"ACC17-001","CustomerType":"Direct Sale"},
{"entity_id":"2","CustomerName":"Test2","AccountNumber":"ACC17-002","CustomerType":"Direct Sale"},
{"entity_id":"3","CustomerName":"Test3","AccountNumber":"ACC17-003","CustomerType":"Direct Sale"},
{"entity_id":"4","CustomerName":"Test4","AccountNumber":"ACC17-004","CustomerType":"Direct Sale"},
{"entity_id":"5","CustomerName":"Test5","AccountNumber":"ACC17-005","CustomerType":"Invoice"},
{"entity_id":"6","CustomerName":"Test6","AccountNumber":"ACC17-006","CustomerType":"Invoice"}
]
```

The first data source is a dynamic sql query...and i need to generate a custom object with the columns of that sql query as the properties of the object and then encode it into JSON for the webservice to reply with.

I am using c# as the intermediate layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the required transformation by installing [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) as shown in *[How to install JSON.NET using NuGet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4444903)* and then using [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to parse and transform your input JSON without making any assumptions about the precise keys and values present.

If `inputJson` is the JSON string you receive from your SQL query, then the following code does the job:

```
// Deserialize the input JSON as an array of arrays of JSON objects
var inputArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject [][]>(inputJson);

// Convert each inner array to a JSON object whose property names come from the nested objects' Key values and property values come from the nested objects' Value values:
var outputArray = inputArray.Select(a => new JObject(a.Select(o => (new JProperty((string)o["Key"], o["Value"])))));

// And re-serialize to JSON.
var outputJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(outputArray, Formatting.Indented);
```

Sample working .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eFCaTg).

Notes:

- I initially deserialize to a `JObject [][]` to ensure the inputs are, in fact, an array of array of objects.
- Initially deserializing to a `KeyValuePair<string, JToken> [][]` also works, as shown [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/urmNRX).