# How to use API docs in C# using JSON (OpenWeatherMap)

Tags: c#, json, wpf, api, openweathermap

I'm trying to create a **`Windows 10 Weather Application`** in ***`WPF`*** using ***`C#`***. I have **`Weather Api`** from [OpenWeatherMap](https://openweathermap.org/forecast16)

I'm using ***`JSON`***. But, I don't know how to implement forecast data. I never used ***`API`*** before. I would be very thankful if you could help.

Comment: For modelling the http rest calls to be called from C# I'm using [RestEase](https://github.com/canton7/RestEase). To generate the needed C# classes for the JSON object I use https://jsonutils.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some useful links to work with json in c#

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Samples.htm#!

[How to install JSON.NET using NuGet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444903/how-to-install-json-net-using-nuget)

http://json2csharp.com/