# Need ideas how to parse the following JSON format

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json-api-response-converter

I have an API that returns JSON data in the following structure:

```
{
  "85f78300-d993-4b7e-a8d0-8d39a4ba9d2a": {},
  "4000fda7-18af-463f-b694-bbafe5d23a48": {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

It should represents a list of objects referenced by a `GUID`. Typically a list of of Objects would look like this:

```
{
  "objects": [
     {...},
     {...},
     ...
  ]
}
```

Currently I have no clue how to parse this result properly. Does anyone have a clue for me?

Comment: Install JSON.NET via NuGet ([see how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444903/how-to-install-json-net-using-nuget)) and use that to parse your JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could treat it as a `Dictionary<Guid, object>`. You can replace `object` with your data type.

```
string json = "{\"85f78300-d993-4b7e-a8d0-8d39a4ba9d2a\": {\"prop\": \"value\"}}";
        
var dict = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<Guid, object>>(json);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, your approach did it for me!